# how can i access mail from a microsoft exchange server using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build a desktop app using electron that retrieves mail from a specific mailbox (microsoft exchange server), now, i have looked around and read that mailbox connection should be done server side (the question was made by a guy building a web based app that is a little bit similar to what i want to do), but, since i am not really deploying a node js server but rather using electron, which, as far as i understand is like a desktop app version of node, im not sure on which approach to take.  Should i use an api? does microsoft has any interface for this? or should i use a third party integration for it?

Comment: i think you should use some API of microsoft to consume in your electron application

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exchanger? https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [Exchange Web Services API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn595099(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_clientapps) is only provided as a CLR assembly, so if you wanted to use it you'd need to:

- write a C# console app that you then spawn from your Electron app
  (and communicate via stdin/stdout), or
- use the EWS API in your Electron app via [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge)

Alternatively, you could probably just directly communicate with the exchange server using SOAP messages, but that could be a bit tedious to implement.

Comment: i finally found the answer by accessing EWS Managed API using node-ews (you can find it on npm although the documentation is scarse) which is a wrapper to send soap messages to an exchange server.

Comment: although the edge.js seems like one of the most interesting things ever :D! ill be sure to try out the ews api from c#

Comment: @Juan Great, I hope [node-ews](https://github.com/nmarus/node-ews) works for you.